# incremental writing to disk

Tags: python, io

I want to do some heavy batch processing and write results to memory using Python. 
Since I will be writing ~30 million records, I/O becomes significant. My strategy is to create the file handle object once in a class constructor, then call `f.write` in a loop.

**Should I implement batching logic myself, or rely on the one implicitly employed by the `write` method?**

I can observe that some buffering is happening implicitly by periodically running `wc -l` on the output. It doesn't go up linearly, instead it goes up every ~5 minutes or so by ~20k lines. Therefore I can only assume that some batching happens internally. Should I therefore assume that my I/O is already optimized?

Alternatively I could:

1. Append my strings to a temporary `list` until a certain batch size is reached
2. Join the list with "\n".join(l) and write with a single call
3. Clean the list and continue

My logic would be a bit more convoluted than the previous overview as my business logic that yields the strings to be written is also happening in batch mode and utilised GPU, which is why I am asking if the above is worth it before attempting it. Also, if you do recommend that approach, I would appreciate a ballpark figure to try for batch size on step 1. My RAM can handle 100k records, would that be optimal?

Comment: Is it necessary to optimize further? If not, you're good. If not, benchmark it for your configuration - test it out. It's (almost) impossible to say for anyone without having detailed knowledge of your architecture. You can use a profiler to see what's actually taking time - the file write operation might be a very small part of the total time and wouldn't matter much in the end.  What you're seeing is that output to files aren't necessarily flushed before the underlying filesystem or operating system decides it's necessary.

Comment: If you are at the point of optimizing IO, then you should not use Python... What I mean is that Python already uses buffered IO when writing to files. So there is little to gain here.

Comment: While i have not properly profiled the code, I believe I/O is a bottleneck. The reason is that when I was profiling my computation only, CPU usage was at 90% for all cores. If I add the writing component utilisation falls to 10% per core. So there is quite some blocking.